# wget seems to crawl only first page when using -A, despite using both -r, -e robots=off, -l inf, etc

Tags: wget

What I want `wget` to do is to crawl the entire site recursively below a certain directory and download all, say, png files.

I'll use Wikipedia as an example. This is the command:

```
wget -r -p -e robots=off -H -D en.wikipedia.org --no-parent -A png http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
```

This is what I get:

```
URL transformed to HTTPS due to an HSTS policy
--2016-07-20 11:02:51--  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
Resolving en.wikipedia.org (en.wikipedia.org)... 91.198.174.192, 2620:0:862:ed1a::1
Connecting to en.wikipedia.org (en.wikipedia.org)|91.198.174.192|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page’

en.wikipedia.org/wi     [  <=>               ]  64.72K   298KB/s    in 0.2s    

2016-07-20 11:02:51 (298 KB/s) - ‘en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page’ saved [66278]

Removing en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page since it should be rejected.

URL transformed to HTTPS due to an HSTS policy
--2016-07-20 11:02:51--  https://en.wikipedia.org/static/images/wikimedia-button.png
Reusing existing connection to en.wikipedia.org:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2426 (2.4K) [image/png]
Saving to: ‘en.wikipedia.org/static/images/wikimedia-button.png’

en.wikipedia.org/st 100%[===================>]   2.37K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2016-07-20 11:02:51 (147 MB/s) - ‘en.wikipedia.org/static/images/wikimedia-button.png’ saved [2426/2426]

URL transformed to HTTPS due to an HSTS policy
--2016-07-20 11:02:51--  https://en.wikipedia.org/static/images/poweredby_mediawiki_88x31.png
Reusing existing connection to en.wikipedia.org:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1585 (1.5K) [image/png]
Saving to: ‘en.wikipedia.org/static/images/poweredby_mediawiki_88x31.png’

en.wikipedia.org/st 100%[===================>]   1.55K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2016-07-20 11:02:51 (102 MB/s) - ‘en.wikipedia.org/static/images/poweredby_mediawiki_88x31.png’ saved [1585/1585]

FINISHED --2016-07-20 11:02:51--
Total wall clock time: 1.0s
Downloaded: 3 files, 69K in 0.2s (316 KB/s)
```

The same happens even if I add `-l inf`.

When I run the same code, but remove `-A png`, `wget` keeps on downloading, with no end in sight, as it's supposed to do.

So, what's the problem? How do I get it to crawl the entire site, but download only certain file types?

Answer (score 0):

The result obtained by the o/p, stanny, is surprising but true.

I get the same result, yet I also get a successful result from an ordinary Wikipedia page, with the following command:-

```
wget --no-check-certificate --span-hosts -e robots=off -p -A png https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimatter
```

I am using wget 1.16, running on a Windows PC using Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Is this an answer ?

Comment: It seems possible that the main page of the Wikipedia site, but only that page, has special protection. I wasn't able to determine what type of extra protection that one page has, but my point is that all other pages on the site, i.e. the actual articles, are accessible to wget. The o/p was only using wikipedia as an example, of how to fetch image files, so I don't see it as worthwhile to spend time on cracking the protection which only applies on one page. My posted code will solve the o/p's problem, if used on almost any other site.